# Cannot see employee class object properties in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, intellisense

I have an Employee class object that I am calling from my "Login.aspx" page's btnContinue_Click event. I am not able to see any of the properties in the intellisense. The Employee.cs file is in the same project as the web application. What confuses me is that the aspx.cs recognizes `Employee oEmp = new Employee();` perfectly well.

What am I doing wrong in the code below?

Here is my code:
**employee.cs**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName  { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CorpID { get; set; }
    public string SignOn { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void btnEmployeeLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (LogInValidated())
            {
                Employee oEmp = new Employee();
                //oEmp.
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dumb question but here goes anyway. Is the Employee class created in some specific namespace? Are you `using` that namespace?

Comment: Do you have any other namespace included in your page having the same class ??? In that case it might be possible that you are creating an object of the other class

Comment: Employee class is in the same namespace as the aspx files

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+Space after your `.` does it bring up intellisense?

Comment: And the Employee.cs file is somewhere in the App_Code folder right?

Comment: @MarkRucker... well, I get intellisense right after I hit .  When I search for FirstName, I see FindControl, Focus, Form etc

Comment: @user1429080... right now the Employee.cs file is in the root of the web application (not in app_code folder)

Comment: Did you try restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: It seems you also have `Employee` as a `UserControl`

Comment: Check @Mark Rucker's updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Visual Studios thinks oEmp is a control on your .aspx page and not a type of your `Employee` class. Have you double checked your .aspx page to make sure you don't have a control with its `ID="oEmp"` and `runat="server"`?

Or are you sure you don't have an `Employee.ascx` file in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your page, you can add:

```
using **here the package of your employee class**;
```

Comment: `using` statement should not include the class name, using is for namespace only

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Customer class is in the same namespace as the btnCustomerLogin_Click event. If it isn't include a using statement at the top of the class.

If you are using visual studio just click on the Employee object and press *Ctrl+'.'* and select the namespace from there.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Employee.cs file so it is under App_Code. That should make VS recognize the class.

If you don't already have an App_Code folder, add it by:

- Right click the web site in VS solution explorer
- Select "`App_Code`" under "`Add Asp.net folder`"

Don't just add a "regular" folder called App_Code.